# ошибка недопустимый ключ

Tags: cmd

Бат файл состоит из

```
echo off
rd /q /s c:\TEMP\new
```

надо удалить папку new вместе с содержимым

при выполнении ошибка- недопустимый ключ: "c:\TEMP\new"

запускаю bat из cmd. если просто написать эту команду, то все работает

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Рекомендую перенабрать строку в батнике (ещё лучше - скопипастить из окна компроцессора, где она сработала) - уж больно похоже на что-то, что выглядит пробелом, но пробелом не является.

Comment: Иногда срабатывает после того как начал пробовать копировать или перенабирать заново. Но зависимость так и не понял. Известно что означает ошибка недопустимый ключ?

Comment: *Известно что означает ошибка недопустимый ключ?* С точки зрения DOS-процессинга ключ - всё, что начинается с символа слэша либо тире после пробела. В данном случае проблема скорее всего именно от того, что между `/s` и именем папки нечто, что видится как пробел, но не пробел (табуляция или иной символ аналогичного толка).

Comment: в общем если в строке из файла удалить ключи а потом написать, то работает. как то теперь надо весь батник править теперь. что еще там вылезет подобное. или конвертор из бат в exe попробовать